# WooCommerce - buying as well as selling

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, customization, development-strategy

Having looked around, I can't find an obvious answer to this one.

Can WooCommerce be configured to have both products available to sell as well as products I offer to buy?

I have looked at setting up a custom product type for these 'buy' products, with custom fields to show my offered price, etc. These products would be 'free' and could be taken through the checkout like normal products.

Is this the right way to go, or is there a simpler method?

Thanks for any suggestions!